# facebook style menu stop position

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I successfully implemented this tutorial in my app but when I slide more than the position of the bottom view, you can see a white line. I want to implement a maximum position of the topLayer (like in Facebook, you can't slide more).

How can I do that? here is my code of the .m file:

http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/9153/screenshot20121209at084.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try this repository, it's very flexible and will let you edit this with ease.

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Comment: Thanks, but I have already downloaded this project but it didn't help me with my problem. I need the code to stop the view at 160 pxs. Any other suggestion? :)